# VueJS - v-on directive - call function after x characters in input

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have this input text field:

```
<input v-model="filterName" v-on:input="search()" type="text" class="form-control" id="carrierName" placeholder="Name">
```

After I type any character into the input text the search() function is called.

What I want is that the search() function is only called when I type at least x characters into my text input.

How can I reach this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can achieve this using an additional handler only:

```
<input v-model="filterName" v-on:input="onInput" type="text" class="form-control" id="carrierName" placeholder="Name">
...
methods: {
  onInput() {
    if (filterName.length > 5) {
      search()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, I know this soultion, thought it is also possible with the v-on directive.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.